# Распараллелить поиск магического числа

Tags: c++, mpi

Необходима помощь в решении следующей задачи (параллельное программирование  MPI)

Условие:
В программе должны быть реализованы следующие функции.
1.  На 0 процессе вводятся размер массива N и диапазон случайных чисел R и магическое число М.
2. Нулевой  процесс генерирует случайный массив A[1..N] c    элементами из диапазона (1.R).
3.  Массив разделяется между всеми узлами равномерно, а так же им рассылается магическое число (исп. операторы коллективного взаимодействия).
4.   Каждый узел изменяет значения элементов массива по правилу :
  If A[i] <> M then
     A[i] = sin(A[i]-M)* exp(A[i])-ln(cos(A[i])). 
 else  программа должна остановится (т.е. каждый узел должен прекратить модифицировать массив А) и массив A остается без изменений. 
5.  В случае если массив А не содержит магическое число М, то он измененный собирается на 0 процессе. 
В случае если массив А содержит М, то 0 процесс должен вывести число итераций которые успели проделать каждый из узлов до остановки .

Примечание:
Остановку реализовать с помощью отложенных запросов.

Проблема в неправильном взаимодействии процессов. Какие-то из них не могут нормально завершить работу (постоянно мигает курсор и больше ничего не происходит после этого). Кроме того, одни процессы успевают завершить свою работу прежде, чем получат сообщение от других

```
Код на си++

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "mpi.h"
#include "fstream"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int change(float* A, int n, int M)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] != M)

            A[i] = sin(A[i] - M)* exp(A[i]) - log(cos(A[i])); 
        else
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

using namespace std;

/*
    Запускай прогу несколько раз подряд, и увидишь как она то работает, то нет, то работает наполовину
*/

void main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    float* A;                   // Исходный массив
    float* resultant_array;   // Обработанный массив

    int id, p;
    int r;
    int s;
    int i;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

    MPI_Request requests[4];
    MPI_Request requests_send[4];

    // Главный процесс
    if (id == 0) {
        int begRandomRange;
        int endRandomRange;
        cout << "Array length: ";
        int N;
        cin >> N; // Вводим размер массива
        int M; // Магическое число
        int j;
        A = new float[N];
        s = N / p;

        // Заполнение массива псевдослучайными числами
        cout << "Begin of random number range:";
        cin >> begRandomRange;
        cout << "End of random number range:";
        cin >> endRandomRange;
        srand(unsigned int(MPI_Wtime()));

        cout << '\n';
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            A[i] = rand() % endRandomRange + begRandomRange;
            cout << A[i] << ' ';
        }
        cout << "\nM:";
        cin >> M;

        // Отправляем магическое число и размер части массива другим процессам
        MPI_Bcast(&M, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(&s, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        resultant_array = new float[s];

        // Разделяем массив на равные части и отправляем другим процессам
        MPI_Scatter(A, s, MPI_FLOAT, resultant_array, s, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        int* iterationCountArray = new int[p];
        iterationCountArray[0] = -1;
        // Инициализация отложенных приёмов
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            MPI_Recv_init(&iterationCountArray[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);
        // Инициализация отложенных передач
        int StopSignal = -1; 
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            MPI_Ssend_init(&StopSignal, 1, MPI_INT, i, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests_send[i]);

        for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            if (resultant_array[i] == M)
            {
                StopSignal = 1;
                MPI_Startall(p, requests_send);
        //      for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
        //          MPI_Isend(&iterationCountArray[0], 1, MPI_INT, j, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests_send[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                resultant_array[i] = -1;
                iterationCountArray[0] = i;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            { 
                //MPI_Test(&requests[j], &StopSignal, &status);
                MPI_Irecv(&StopSignal, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j]);
                if (StopSignal > 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (StopSignal > 0)
            {
                cout << '\n' << "id: " << id << " IterCountArray: " << i;
                break;
            }
        }       
        cout << '\n';
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        bool flag;
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            if (iterationCountArray[i] != N)
                flag = 1;
        if (flag)
        {   // Собираем массив по частям из других потоков, включая этот
            float *result_A = new float[N];
            MPI_Gather(resultant_array, s, MPI_FLOAT, result_A, s, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            for (i = 0; i < s*p; i++)
                cout << result_A[i] << " ";
        }   
        cin >> id;
    }
    else {
        int M;
        int StopSignal = -1;
        // Ждём получения магического числа и размера части массива от процесса 0
        MPI_Bcast(&M, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Магическое число
        MPI_Bcast(&s, 1, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Размерность
        resultant_array = new float[s];
        // Получаем свою часть массива от процесса 0
        MPI_Scatter(&A, s, MPI_FLOAT, resultant_array, s, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        // Инициализация отложенных передач
        int IterationCount = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            MPI_Ssend_init(&IterationCount, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests_send[i]);
        // Инициализация отложенного приёма
        for (i = 0; i < p; i++)
            MPI_Recv_init(&StopSignal, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[i]);
        for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            if (resultant_array[i] == M)
            {
                StopSignal = 1;
                MPI_Startall(p, requests_send);
            //  for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            //      MPI_Isend(&IterationCount, 1, MPI_INT, j, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests_send[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                resultant_array[i] = -1; 
                IterationCount = i;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
            {
                //MPI_Test(&requests[j], &StopSignal, &status);
                MPI_Irecv(&StopSignal, 1, MPI_INT, j, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requests[j]);
                if (StopSignal > 0)
                    break;
            }
            if (StopSignal > 0)
            {
                cout << '\n' << "id: " << id << " IterCountArray: " << i;
                break;
            }
        }
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        IterationCount = i;
        MPI_Gather(resultant_array, s, MPI_FLOAT, A, s, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```